# Connect custom table view cell to separate view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I'm trying to connect my custom table view cell into a table view in my main VC. The cell has its own xib file and its own swift file. I originally had the cell set up as a custom prototype cell in the table.

So the problem I have is in connecting my new custom cell to the viewcontroller. The code I have now is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
UITableViewCell {
    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as! CustomTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

Of course this set up is not working. The error I get during runtime is: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" which I assume is referring to "cell" identifier. So my question is, can I connect my cell to this function, or do I need a new one to initiate and return "cell" to this table view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the cell with the `UITableView` before you can use it. In your `viewDidLoad` method you need something like the following.

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```